# How do I download email attachemnts with IMAP and PHP?

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments

I am trying to retrieve a file that is emailed to me every day as an attachment.  I need to retrieve the attachment to my Linux server.  What is the simplest way to make this happen?

Thanks for any help!

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, IMAP Functions, what are the functions that download the attached files ? (even if we don't explicitely want to download them)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194083/in-php-imap-functions-what-are-the-functions-that-download-the-attached-files)

Comment: Also [How to save image attachment from email using IMAP & PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2292199) and some more in the "Related" list

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for me is to use a library for this task. For example my favorite is [Zeta Components - Mail](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#retrieving-mail-using-imap) which have a good tutorial.